# Swift Auto-Renewable Subscription Problems

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, in-app-purchase

For the last 7 days I have been trying to create the **Auto-Renewable Subscription**.I have done it without the **Shared Secret**,i was following a [tutorial](http://www.lynda.com/iOS-tutorials/Validating-receipt-server/171727/352322-4.html),and the working code was with Storing Information on cloud.I wanted to use Reciept Validation but the code in the tutorial was full of bugs,and also the PHP code was full of errors.I have found another free tutorial, but the same thing,only bugs,no way of making it run.Till now I have searched the whole GitHub,i have payed the Lynda tutorial,and found lots of other tutorials but non of them is working.Is there any tutorial that you might suggest me,or can you help me out with the code.

Here is the swift code which has 2 bugs:
[Bugs in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2sVS.png)
func validateReceipt(){

```
var receiptUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL
var receipt: NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(receiptUrl!, options: nil, error: nil)

var response: NSURLResponse?
var error: NSError?

var receiptdata:NSString = receipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://mm214.com/write.php")!)
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

var err: NSError?

request.HTTPBody = receiptdata.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    var err: NSError?
    var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

    if err != nil  {
        print(err!.localizedDescription)
        let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
    }
    else {
        if let parseJSON = json {
            println("Receipt \(parseJSON)")
        }
        else {
            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Receipt Error: \(jsonStr)")
        }
    }
})

task.resume()
```

Here is the php code:

```
<?php
        function getReceiptData($receipt)
        {
            $fh = fopen('showme.txt',w);
            fwrite($fh,$receipt);
            fclose($fh);
            $endpoint = 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';

            $ch = curl_init($endpoint);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $receipt);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $msg = $response.' - '.$errno.' - '.$errmsg;
            echo $response;
        }

    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
        $newcontent .= $key.' '.$value;
    }

    $new = trim($newcontent);
    $new = trim($newcontent);
    $new = str_replace('_','+',$new);
    $new = str_replace(' =','==',$new);

    if (substr_count($new,'=') == 0){
    if (strpos('=',$new) === false){
            $new .= '=';
    }
    }

    $new = '{"receipt-data":"'.$new.'","password":"shared secreet"}';
    $info = getReceiptData($new);
    ?>
```

I'm getting the error on 31 line :

> Warning: strpos(): Empty needle in
>   /home2/arslan/public_html/verifyReciep.php on line 31 {"status":21002}

Comment: So you are sending receipt data to Php server and Php server using receipt data to communicate with iTunes server for receipt validation. Make sure you are getting proper receipt.

Comment: Yes thats correct couse it can be manipulated if i talk directly to the itunes server.The problem is in my code if you know how to solve it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

21002 - The data in the receipt-data property was malformed or missing.

Here receipt malformed when you convert it to `NSData`.

In the iOS 7 , Apple introduced new base64 methods on NSData that make it unnecessary to use a 3rd party base 64 decoding library , but i still suggest you to try to use [Base64](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64) encoding for receipt encoding. I hope this will solve your problem. As i also face same issue of 21002 when I verify receipt from server side and this encoding library works in this case. Don't know How , but it solved my issue at server side for receipt validation call. Hope it will work for you also.

Follow given steps :

1. Download [Base64](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64) from here.
2. Add `Base64.h` and `Base64.m` in your project.
   [image]
3. Add bridging header to use Objective C file in Swift class.
   [image]

To create [Bridging Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716413/xcode-not-automatically-creating-bridging-header).

4. Now use `base64EncodedString()` of added class.

Follow my answer for more detail. [In-app purchase receipt verification for auto renewal using AFNetworking objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452736/in-app-purchase-receipt-verification-for-auto-renewal-using-afnetworking-objecti/34453527#34453527)

Comment: Can you help me a bit with it.

Comment: So im getting the error on let encodeddata = data!.base64EncodedString(); NSHasNomember of base64Endocing and expirationDateFromResponse has no member.

Comment: Just download Base 64 encoding decoding files from this link and add it to project and use it. https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64

Comment: Answer updated for step wise integration of Base64 class. This will surely work for you. Thanks

Comment: Thanks what do i place here?            requestContents.setObject(encodeddata, forKey: "receipt-data");
            requestContents.setObject("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", forKey: "password");

Comment: You have to send your sharedSecret as password to server.

Comment: So i place my shared secret pass there?

Comment: Yes, server needs shared secret as password to communicate with iTunes server. You can find shared secret from iTunes store .

Comment: Sorry can you help me out I'm getting the json.But I'm unable to validate it in the correct way.Can you help me i will send you my code ?

Comment: So, now what error code you getting in receipt validation . Are you getting 21004 ?

Comment: It's not an error.I get the json output,but when i follow the tutoral from lynda with the non working validation.I have placed this validation,but its not calling it.Here is my code https://gist.github.com/ArslanHaj/679d4a1df236bacdb9c8

Comment: Ok, i will check it.

Comment: Thanks a lot sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Please answer my comment on gist.

Comment: I have 2min ago sorry i havet seen it at the beggining.